# compare value with 2 different columns using the IN operator

Tags: sql, sql-server-2019

I have a situation where I need to compare the value of a column with 2 columns from my settings table.

Currently I have this query which works

```
declare @t int = 3
select 1
where  @t = (select s.RelationGDGMID from dbo.tblSettings s )
       or 
       @t = (select s.RelationGTTID from dbo.tblSettings s )
```

But I wonder if I can make this without reading tblSettings 2 times, and then I tried this

```
declare @t int = 3
select 1 
where  @t in (select s.RelationGDGMID, s.RelationGTTID from dbo.tblSettings s )
```

and this does not compiles, it returns

> Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the
> subquery is not introduced with EXISTS

So how can I do this without reading tblSettings 2 times, well one solution would be using the EXISTS like the error hints me

```
declare @t int = 3
select 1 
where  exists (select 1 from dbo.tblSettings s where s.RelationGDGMID = @t or s.RelationGTTID = @t)
```

and yes that works, only reads tblSettings once, so I can use this.
But I still wonder if there is a way to make it work with the `IN` operator
After all, when I do this

```
declare @t int = 3
select 1 
where @t in (3, 1)
```

that works without problems,
so why does

```
where  @t in (select s.RelationGDGMID, s.RelationGTTID from dbo.tblSettings s )
```

not works, when in fact it also returns `(3, 1)` ?

Comment: Essentially, you need your list as rows and not columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it would be to use UNION if the columns are of the same type.

```
where @t in (select s1.RelationGDGMID from dbo.tblSettings s1 UNION
select s2.RelationGTTID from dbo.tblSettings s2)
```

The reason this works is because it is returning one value set (1 column with values). The reason `where @t in (3, 1)` works is because this the same, it is returning one value set (value 3 and value 1).

That said I would prefer the `EXISTS` over `IN` as this could produce a better query plan.

Comment: Well I have no problem in using the exists, I just wonder why the IN does not works that way

Comment: `because it is returning one value set (1 column with values). ` Yes off course, that makes a whole lot of sense. I should have know this. Thanks for the explanation

Comment: Because you're trying to compare a "list" of *scalar* values to what is effectively a "list" of tuples, @GuidoG . You wouldn't compare an `int` to an array in C#; the same applies in SQL.

Comment: @Larnu Yes you are right, after the edit to this answer I finally woke up and saw the reason why.